# SQL Server stored procedure only returning one value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I having some issues when returning a stored procedure, I need all selects in order to create a chart.

This is my procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LastWeekQuotesByAssociate]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        networkid, COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total 
    FROM
        email 
    WHERE
        (networkID = 'crbark00' 
        AND emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) 
    GROUP BY
        networkID

    SELECT 
        networkid, COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total 
    FROM
        email 
    WHERE
        (networkID = 'crherb00' 
        AND emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) 
    GROUP BY
        networkID

    SELECT 
        networkid,
        COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total 
    FROM
        email 
    WHERE
        (networkID = 'crcalr25'
        AND emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) 
    GROUP BY
        networkID

   SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'craran00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crcerg25'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crdelj00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crromj00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crarrl00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crverj00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crmore00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crgomf00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crvarm00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crmong00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crarim00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crjimj00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crvilg00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID 
END
```

And this is when executing:

```
USE [Quotes]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[LastWeekQuotesByAssociate]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

It only returns first select!

Any hint, someone can help me out here!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it that way, you need to add

```
UNION ALL
```

between every select.

```
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crbark00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
UNION ALL
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email where(networkID = 'crherb00'and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
```

Better solution would be to generate list/ table containing networkIds and then use 'in' like:

```
SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total 
from email 
where 
    networkID in ('crbark00', 'crbark01', 'crbark02') 
    and emailDateEntry > DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()) 
group by networkID
```

Perhaps could use subselect instead of listing each networkId

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT networkid,COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total from email 
      where networkID  in ('crbark00','crxxxxx') 
      and emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) group by networkID
```

Comment: Instead of using where...=...or...= it would be better to use the `IN ()` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Please use UNION ALL command once every select statement got complete like Example 
SELECT 
        networkid, COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total 
    FROM
        email 
    WHERE
        (networkID = 'crbark00' 
        AND emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) 
    GROUP BY
        networkID
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        networkid, COUNT(isQuoteComplete) as Total 
    FROM
        email 
    WHERE
        (networkID = 'crherb00' 
        AND emailDateEntry > (DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()))) 
    GROUP BY
        networkID